# Inject script inside ajax loaded div

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm using Jquery in my site and I have a div with content loaded by ajax, like an iFrame. With my code I can access the content and even change the class and values, but I can't insert a script to be executed.

**There is the code:**

```
<script>
$("#loginsb").click(function () {

$('#curso')
          .contents()
          .find('#script').jQuery("<script>").prop("tagName")
          .attr('src', load.js);
});
</script>
```

My ajax loaded div is *curso* and inside this div I have another div *script* where I placed the the script line - without the src. Is the only way I knew to use more than one script in my page and *find* just one of them.

**Inside *Curso* div**

```
<div id="script">
<script></script>
</div>
```

Any idea to attribute this src inside my div script? Thanks!

Comment: I think your approach is incorrect. Why would you need a script to being written into a document tag after it's being loaded in ajax?

Comment: Thank you, Kondziutek. My elements inside this document have animations and I need they to run after the user click in one button from the other page. The script do that, but if I load with the rest of page, the elements will run before the click.

Comment: `.prop("tagName")` returns the tagName, as in the string `"script"`, it has no method `.attr()`

Comment: Sorry, adeneo, but I don't understand. I learn about Jquery in the last 2 weeks, so, my programming is a mess right now. Can you tell me how I fix that?

Comment: If its a div on same page then $('#curso').find('script').attr('src', 'load.js');

Comment: Is not in the same page and I have more than one script on the page, Jaya.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You miss some basics in understanding Javascript and jQuery. 
First thing: you can only have one element with id="script" and in your example you have one script element inside it.

So you can target that script element inside the script id element using jQuery:

```
$('#script script')
```

Then adjust the source of the script:

```
$('#script script').attr('src', 'load.js');
```

(Note the quotation marks around load.js. this is a string literal not a variable or constant.)